# APT method bzip2 doesn't exist

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I tried to update my system on Xubuntu  : sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade.

I got this error message :

```
E: Le pilote pour la méthode /usr/lib/apt/methods/bzip2 n'a pu être trouvé.
```

In english the driver for the method /usr/lib/apt/methods/bzip2 can't be found.

I checked the folder :

```
$ ls /usr/lib/apt/methods/
cdrom  copy  file  ftp  gpgv  gzip  http  https  mirror  rred  rsh  ssh  xz
```

Actually for the moment, APT can't install anything cause it can't unzip with bzip2 : the method doesn't exist inside the proper folder.

Comment: Try a `sudo apt-get install bzip2`. If that not work, give me the output of `lsb_release -a; uname -a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt` does not depend on `bzip2` - `bzip2` is only a symbolic link to `gzip`.

Create the link

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/apt/methods/gzip /usr/lib/apt/methods/bzip2
```

---

Install `bzip2`

```
sudo apt-get install bzip2
```

Alternative

```
apt-get download bzip2
sudo dpkg -i bzip2*.deb
```

Comment: Hello, I created the links and it works fine now. Thanks a lot

Comment: Dont't thank me. **;)** Accept the answer with a click on the check mark at the left side of the answer.